# No cookie for you!

Tags: bug

Since a week or so, all SE sites repeatedly ask for accepting cookies. And regardless how often I click "accept all", the next subsite or call after a browser restart asks again. (I checked, my NoScript is set on accepting all SE scripts? Hmm, is it? Nevermind, this never happened before even with scripts blocked.)

Someone an idea what is wrong here? Could be as well on my side. (I have a standard Firefox running.) Anybody experience this too?

Comment: There are several other users with similar problems; you could check the [\[cookies\] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cookies?tab=Newest) on Meta Stack Exchange for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For the first time I'm answering my own question (even if this is kind of silly), because I think I found the reason and it might help others:

Clicking on "OK to all scripts" in the NoScript plugin (and maybe any similar) does NOT OK all scripts! Because these are just the SE scripts, which postload even more scripts, and "cookielaw.org" was NOT OK'ed, and it handles the SE cookies. After I accepted that one, the problem was gone...on chess SE, that is.

It seems that the site sets a cookie for *any* SE subsite and I must also repeat OK'ing for any subsite, but then, it's only a handful I visit...

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. I had the same problem on one device where as well as an adblocker I use something which I think is called MuMatrix which aggressively blocks a lot more stuff in a customizable way (you can look at what it is doing and change it). Everything was OK for me, then my MuMatrix device started played up - every refresh a request to OK cookies - the a couple of days ago back to normal again. I didn't change anything (apart from using that device much less for SE access) so I assume StackExchange changed something.